# How to do a sudo verification that lasts long enough for (unprivileged) make to finish?

Tags: sudo

I often use the following construct for building and installing a tarball:

```
sudo -v && make && sudo make install
```

which will allow me to enter my password immediately and have everything done unattended. This works well except in the rare case that building takes longer than the `sudo` timeout, which may happen on my rather slow machine with large projects (even when using `make -j4`).

But when the build takes a long time, that's exactly when doing things unattended has a great advantage. Can anyone think of a shell construct that allows me to input my password immediately, and which has `make` executing under normal permissions and `make install` under elevated permissions?

For security reasons, I don't want to configure my user to use `sudo` without password.

A viable option is to set the timeout to very long, but I'm hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Have your consider configuring your user to use `sudo` without password ?

Comment: Here is a howto about this question. http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/how-to-change-sudo-password-time-out-in.html

Comment: thanks, I know about those options, but I was hoping for something more elegant. I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're gained root privileges, you can use `sudo` again to execute a command as the non-root user:

```
sudo bash -c "sudo -u $USER non-root-user-command ; root-command"
```

Note that you need to use double quotes, not single quotes. If you use single quotes, `$USER` will be replaced with `root`, which won't achieve the desired outcome. Hopefully, these commands will illustrate my point:

```
$ sudo bash -c "echo $USER"
david
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $USER'
root
```

---

So, let's take the example mentioned in the question:

```
 make && sudo make install
```

That would become:

```
 sudo bash -c "sudo -u $USER make && make install"
```

Comment: This has the additional advantage of checking the exit value of `make` before attempting `make install`. Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
make | sudo bash -c 'cat - && make install'
```

This will start both `make` and `sudo` simultaneously, with `sudo` prompting for your password. In the mean time, `make` sends all its output to the pipe, which is read by the `cat` command. After this is done, `make install` is run. It is invoked from the `bash` process, which still has elevated permissions, so there's no timeout issue.

Comment: @Flimm: the point is that this will give you the sudo prompt immediately instead of after the make command finishes.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. That's clever.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method that does not require you to alter your system files:

```
echo {password} | sudo -S -v && make && echo {password} | sudo -S make install
```

This will allow the script to run without prompting for a password.

However, this method poses a security risk since you're storing your password in plain text.

---

[Some other methods can be found here](http://www.howtogeek.com/116757/8-ways-to-tweak-and-configure-sudo-on-ubuntu/) but most are about editing system files.

---

edit:
If you add a space in front of the first echo the command will not be shown in the bash history.

Comment: excellent! I will accept this as soon as I'm convinced that there's no way to keep the password off the command line.

Comment: Oh this can be made more ingenious by reading a file (SUSE can do that ;) )

Comment: that much is obvious, but it would be nice if we could make it more ingenious by having it still come from an invisible terminal input.

Comment: Can the negative voter please explain their reason?

Comment: That was me. I downvoted because of the security risks you mentioned, and because this answer appeared before Timo Kluck's answer.

Comment: You need to read up on when it is appropriate to do so @Flimm Why is being earlier to answer a reason for a downvote? And the security risc is there since the password is echo'd in plain text. It is a fair warning that TS decided to take into account when accepting the other answer. (or now yours since it seems to have switched).

Comment: I consider this answer relative to the other answers a bad answer, because it unnecessarily introduces a security risk. If the security risk was necessary, I wouldn't downvote it. The space before the command trick only works when `HISTCONTROL` is `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`, which might not be the case if the user has modified `.bashrc`.

Comment: @flimm incorrect again. Answers need to be with a **vanilla** Ubuntu in mind otherwise topicstarter needs to state the changes in their question. For the same reason we do not accept questions about Mint.

Comment: I disagree that we shouldn't expect users to modify their `.bashrc` file when discussing security implications of an answer.

Comment: @Flimm, @Rinzwind: I think that it doesn't warrant a downvote if there are security implications **as long as those are explained**. Rinzwind does that -- although he could have mentioned the file `.bash_history` explicitly. Also, I would only downvote based on the merits of the answer itself, not based on its merit relative to the other answers.